# Can we have a mod tool to prevent posts from being selected for review audits, without invalidating flags?

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderator-tools, review-audits, disputed-flags

I've been wanting to ask this question for some time.

This question is a clear example of the need for the request:

[Wrong review question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371834/wrong-review-question)

Quoting from the [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371849/3956566):

> I handled the flags and should have then cleared the flags to prevent the post being used as a review audit, as it's not obviously to most users that it's spam.

However clearing the flags, changes the status of the post and makes the posts visible on the site for >10K users.

There's quite a few instances where we will clear the flags on a post to prevent it from being in a review audit.

It's still a problem:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377788/3956566

Answer (score 2):

[This fix](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377864/3956566) will alleviate many of the issues associated with the posts being used audits that a mod may want to prevent. As such, this feature request has been addressed.

> As of today (December 14, 2018), any validated "rude or abusive" flags on a post will make that post ineligible for use as a "known-bad" audit in either the Triage or the Low Quality review queues.
>
> Additionally, I've added checks to ensure that only posts which were actually deleted by the system in response to spam flags are used for this purpose - this should avoid situations where posts deleted for other reasons (for instance, due to the destruction of their author's account) are used. Such posts are often offensive, confusing or otherwise misleading in the context of an audit, and thus relying on confirmed spam should avoid some unnecessary distress for reviewers here

It won't solve issues such as [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377860/failed-audit-on-a-code-only-answer), but that is something that is beyond mod control.